# Maximo exceeds maximum field length

Tags: database, maximo

I am having an issue with a maximo import.
I receive an error saying the value for description exceeds maximum field length.
However I have done =len() on the excel file for description and the maximum field length matches the maximum field length in maximo.

Could this be something else?

Comment: fixed - just had to reduce it down to 97 characters instead of 100 - not sure why 100 weren't working but it's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may have been multi-byte characters. Paste the text into Notepad++, or another editor with similar functionality, and turn on all characters (press the "paragraph" button, like in Word). Some of your spaces may not be plain spaces or something. For comparison, copy the string to just Notepad, then copy it from there to Notepad++ under the copy from Excel.

Comment: Wouldn't multi-byte characters paste in the last byte only?

Comment: Who can say how programmers of the various pieces of software or their programming language would have handled the problem? Apparently it wasn't as we hoped.. ;-)

Comment: True. We use US7ASCII w/ Oracle and that's how data is entered for us. Multi-byte is not supported in our configuration, but in Karen's case this may not be the case...?